# Electron "unminimize"

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm trying to find a way to make electron go from minimized, back to the last size of the open app - that is, simulating what happens when you click on a minimized app normally.

What I ideally want (but obviously doesn't work as it is not a function):

```
if (mainWindow.isMinimized()) {
    mainWindow.unminimize()
  }
```

What would also be acceptable, but I haven't been able to get to work:

```
if (mainWindow.isMinimized()) {
    mainWindow.setSize(1100, 950)
  }
```

What currently works, but doesn't bring me the desired result:

```
if (mainWindow.isMinimized()) {
    mainWindow.maximize()
  }
```

If anyone has a cool trick to simulate this function, or atleast a tip on how to go from minimized to a set screen size, you'd make my day! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Electron.js How to minimize/close window to system tray and restore window back from tray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37828758/electron-js-how-to-minimize-close-window-to-system-tray-and-restore-window-back)

Comment: Have you tried `mainWindow.restore()`? https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winrestore

Comment: I hadn't! That's exactly what I was looking for! Cheers :) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFIAK `mainWindow.setSize(width, height[, animate])` doesn't know about the window state (i.e. maximized or minimzed). Therefore changing the size parameters with `mainWindow.setSize()` won't effect the state of the window.

As OliverRadini points out you can use `mainWindow.restore()`. The [docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winrestore) are pretty simple...

> win.restore()
>
> Restores the window from minimized state to its previous state.

So, using your code you should be able to do...

```
if (mainWindow.isMinimized()) {
    mainWindow.restore()
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking to restore the window size using the maximize button after it's been maximized:

```
onMaximizeWindow() {
    if (this.electronService.window.isMaximized()) this.electronService.window.restore();
    else this.electronService.window.maximize();
  }
```