# function quitAndInstall of electron-updater

Tags: node.js, windows, electron, electron-builder, electron-updater

As this post : [Electron auto update fails silently when installing update on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58126745/electron-auto-update-fails-silently-when-installing-update-on-windows)

I can't install my new update :( check update, download is good but during installation of the update, the progress bar fills up halfway, then disappears.

The app remains closed and does not automatically relaunch after the progress bar disappears.

i don't have error with log... i use the v4.2.0 of electron-updater.

[UPDATE]

waiting the real solution i have make this code for auto-update on windows :

```
if(process.platform != 'win32') {
   autoUpdater.quitAndInstall();
} else {
   // to find info of next version get pair "filename":"<appName>-Setup-<version>.exe"
   let pathOfPending = homedir + '\\AppData\\Local\\' + process.env.npm_package_name + '-updater\\pending\\';
   let updateInfo = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(pathOfPending + 'update-info.json'));
   console.log(updateInfo.fileName);
   exec(pathOfPending + updateInfo.fileName, function(err, data) {
      console.log(err);
      //don't forget to exit your app because the setup launches the app too
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if your `createBroswser` has closable set to false.

If you have set closable = false, remove it.