# How to hide electron app on startup in tray

Tags: node.js, electron

I have a electron app with a 'hide to tray' function like in this answer "https://stackoverflow.com/a/38980563/16312733".

But I want that the application doesn't open/show the main windows on startup.

I saw that here is already a question about that "[Auto launch to system tray on system startup - Electron + Ionic app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63524623/auto-launch-to-system-tray-on-system-startup-electron-ionic-app)" but this question is already a year old and I think this question doesnt get a answer any time soon.

So is there a way to hide the main window on startup so the software is only visible in the tray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your app is about to create its main windows (`BrowserWindow`) you can use the option `show` to keep the window hidden after creation.

```js
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ show: false });
// Window will be created but stays hidden
```

After that you can just show it manually whenever you are ready

```js
mainWindow.show();
```

Read [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window/#using-ready-to-show-event) in the official docs .